# How to increase score when clone prefabs touch wall?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CountScoreAtWall : MonoBehaviour
{
   // Variables
   public GameObject[] prefabs;
   public Text animalPassedText;
   public int animalPassed;

   // Start is called before the first frame update
   void Start()
   {
   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {
       animalPassedText.text = animalPassed.ToString();
   }

   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
   {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == tag)
        {
            animalPassed = animalPassed + 1;
            Debug.Log("Animal Passed showed");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to let my clone Prefabs from Instantiate() touch the wall and then the score will Increase by 1 to animalPassedText but I don't know how to do that.

So please help me. ToT

Comment: Are you sure OnTriggerEnter is working? Do you see "Animal Passed showed" in the console when prefabs touch the wall? And what is tag here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1- Either the wall or your prefab should have a rigidbody to make OnTriggerEnter work. So check if one of your game objects has a rigidbody and they both have colliders.

2- Maybe your "tag" variable is not matching with collision.gameObject.tag, so if block is not triggered. Print *collision.gameObject.tag* and *tag* to see if they are matching.

Comment: Now I found the answer. Thank you for helping. love you <3